# PyOpenGL program doesn't show cube?

Tags: python, numpy, opengl, pygame, pyopengl

I'm trying to draw a 3D cube using Python and its packages, pygame, numpy, PyOpenGL, and PyOpenGL_accelerate. The 3D cube also rotates to other directions when I press the arrow buttons. For example, it rotates to right when I press the right arrow.

First, I've tried it on other PC and it runs perfectly. But then, I've also tried it on my laptop and when I run it, it doesn't show anything in the screen. I successfully installed the required packages and all but it still doesn't show anything.

Here's my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

pygame.init()

display = (800, 600)
pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

pygame.display.set_caption("03 lab 1 ")

gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)
glTranslatef(0, 0, -5)

angle = 1
rotatex = 0
rotatey = 0
rotatez = 0


def draw_cube():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0)

    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0)


    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 1)
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 1)
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 1)
    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 1)


    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 1)
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 1)
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 1)
    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 1)

    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 1)

    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 1)

    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 1)

    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 1)

    glEnd()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    rotatey -= 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    rotatex += 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    rotatey += 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    rotatex -= 1


        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

glRotate(angle, rotatex, rotatey,rotatez)
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.time.wait(15)
draw_cube()
```

So, here's my output. It just show a blank screen.

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the display after drawing the cube. Call `pygame.display.flip()` after `glEnd()`. You need to redraw the cube in each frame and change the rotation matrix in each frame. It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). The indentation of the application loop is wrong.

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

pygame.init()

display = (800, 600)
pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

pygame.display.set_caption("03 lab 1 ")

gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)
glTranslatef(0, 0, -5)

angle = 1
rotatex = 0
rotatey = 0
rotatez = 0


def draw_cube():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0)

    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0)


    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 1)
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 1)
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 1)
    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 1)


    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 1)
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 1)
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 1)
    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 1)

    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 1)

    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 1)

    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 1)

    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0)
    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 1)

    glEnd()

# INDENTATION
#<--| 

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                rotatey -= 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                rotatex += 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                rotatey += 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                rotatex -= 1


    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        quit()

    # INDENTATION
#-->|

    glRotate(angle, rotatex, rotatey,rotatez)
    draw_cube()
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(15)
```

Comment: The rotate and wait calls probably need to be there too, although I think more needs to change to actually make the cube rotate.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested. It does show the cube but it's not rotating.

Comment: @Ai-Yue Of course not. You have to redraw r cube in every frame and you habe to change the rotation matrix in every frame. It's a matter of indentation. The indentation of the applikation loop ist wrong.